# creating navigation based on models with foreign keys

Tags: django

I'm having trouble finding a solution, or even where to look for a solution to this, and am a beginner with Django. I'd like to create a dynamic navigation for a project I'm working on.

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

class League(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    crest       = models.ImageField(upload_to='league-crests/', default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Club(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    crest       = models.ImageField(upload_to='club-crests/', default=0)
    league      = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Basically I'd like a top level nav called "Leagues" with a dropdown list of all leagues saved in the database. For each league i'd like a second level dropdown with the clubs in each league.

I've been googling around but haven't found anything pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all League records with

```
leagues = League.objects.all()
```

Then you can pass this to a template and loop round adding options to your dropdown html using:

```
{% for league in leagues %}
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{ league.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If you put a `related_name` of `clubs` on your foreign key then you can reference the related records for each league as well using `league.clubs`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I achieve the sub-level for each league, with each club listed per league? And what's best practice for feeding this to base.html/all templates? through a context_processor.py file?

Comment: Sorry, added a bit to my answer. You already have a Fk relation, so you can use that to access the related records.